# Basic development on the Gnome platform

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, passwords, gnome

I'm trying to write a C++ application on Gnome/Ubuntu as my first non-academic exercise in programming and I'm having trouble getting started with it. I can't find any information on the different header files I need to include in order to access the functions in the Gnome API. I've looked around the Gnome developer site and found a few example programs that contain the lines

```
#include <glib-object.h>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "config.h"
```

However, these are just examples of the use of these particular headers and don't tell me what functionality they provide in general. I've found the Gnome API documentation, but that just contains a list of all the available functions without any context.

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is getting at the passwords stored in the Gnome Keyring. There's some [example code](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/StoringPasswords) that details how to store and retrieve passwords but those are just snippets from larger programs and don't tell me how to get started writing one.

There are two things I'm looking for here:

1. The most important one is finding out about the available headers on Gnome. Where can I learn about what ones there are, what functionality they provide and what packages I need to install to be able to use them.
2. This one doesn't matter if the above one gets sorted out, but if it doesn't, then a complete example program that retrieves a password from the Gnome Keyring and stores it as a variable would help me get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all documentation and tutorials at [developer.gnome.org](http://developer.gnome.org/).

Additionally you can use `pkg-config` tool which will tell you include and library paths. For Gnome Keyring it gives the following:

```
user@home:~$ pkg-config gnome-keyring-1 --libs
-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lgnome-keyring -lglib-2.0  

user@home:~$ pkg-config gnome-keyring-1 --cflags
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I've already been there and while the info there is extensive, I can't figure out what what headers are required to use the functions detailed in the API reference documentation and the Devhelp application.

Comment: You need to include only `gtkmm.h` to use GTK+ as noted in [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/). Which headers you're talking about?

Comment: Gtkmm is just for interface programming, but there's a whole heap of infrastructure provided by Gnome. I mentioned the Gnome Keyring in my question, and the API documentation for that can be found here: http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-keyring/stable/. I'm trying to find out how I include the functions described therein in my application.

Comment: Most Gnome application files simply include `gnome.h` for including Gnome headers and `gtkmm.h` for GTK+. If you want to include only one or two functions you can explore the source code, but why do you need it?

Comment: I'm trying to get my application to authenticate with Ubuntu One, using the Ubuntu One OAuth token stored in the keychain.

Comment: Actually, I think it was `gnome.h` I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't it. `gnome.h` isn't found by the compiler and some googling says that it's part of the `gnome1.0-dev` package, which is a rather old library.